# Run Command does not save file on EC2 instance (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I am having this problem using a run command on an EC2 instance. The run command is simple, something like:

```
echo "$token" >> "/var/lib/sftd/enrolment.token"
echo "Test: Check what is in the token file"
cat /var/lib/sftd/enrollment.token
```

This return the token as expected!

However on the EC2 instance itself, the token file is not created... how can that be?

Comment: Seems you are writing to `enrolment.token` and reading from `enrolment.token`. There is a typo.

Comment: sorry, they should both be enrollment.token, thats a typo here in stackoverflow - and not the source of my problem. I actually get the token when I use "cat" as above, but its not stored on the ec2 instance for some reason when i go to /var/lib/stfd/enrollment.token

Comment: What SSM Command are you running?  AWS-RunShellScript?

Comment: AWS-RunShellScript